# Calling a method within another method in the context of @property

Tags: python, oop, methods, decorator

With the following sample code containing @property decorators:

```
class Grade_Calculator(object):
    def __init__(self,score):
        self.score = score

    @property
    def grade(self):
        if self.score in range(60,70):
            grade = 'D'
        elif self.score in range(70,80):
            grade = 'C'
        elif self.score in range(80,90):
            grade = 'B'
        elif self.score in range(90,101):
            grade = 'A'
        return grade

    @property
    def failure(self):
        if self.score < 60:
            print 'See me'
            grade = 'F'
            return grade
```

and an instance:

```
g = Grade_Calculator(28)
```

`g.grade` returns an `UnboundLocalError`.  I would like to call `failure()` within `grade()` to avoid this error.

With an instance:

```
g = Grade_Calculator(89)
```

`g.failure()` fails silently. I would like to call `grade()` within `failure()` to act as a fail-safe in this situation.

I've seen a lot of references to just doing `self.method()` calls, but they're not working for me and I think the presence of the decorator is screwing me up somehow:

```
@property
def grade(self):
    if self.score < 60:
        self.failure()
    elif self.score in range(60,70):
        grade = 'D'
    elif self.score in range(70,80):
        grade = 'C'
    elif self.score in range(80,90):
        grade = 'B'
    elif self.score in range(90,101):
        grade = 'A'
    return grade

g = Grade_Calculator(28)
g.grade
See me
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-667-fb10e6cf27d4> in <module>()
----> 1 g.grade

./sample.py in grade(self)
      6     def grade(self):
      7         if self.score < 60:
----> 8             self.failure()
      9         elif self.score in range(60,70):
     10             grade = 'D'

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

What am I not understanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined `failure` as a property. Therefore, you can't call it using `()` notation; in fact, not doing that is kinda the whole point of using a property. `self.failure` returns `'F'` and you then try to call it, which is why you get the error about not being able to call a string. It's as if you wrote `'F'()` which is an obvious mistake.

Also, you're throwing away the value you get from `failure` and you're only returning a value in the case of failure (which means you get `None` otherwise). Of course you only access `failure` if you have a failing grade to begin with... in which case you don't need to check that condition inside `failure`, now do you?

Also, printing stuff in properties is pretty bad style. You don't expect something to be printed when you access an attribute. Separation of concerns: something outside of the class should probably be doing the printing, or you should have a separate method to call to print whatever is returned by `grade`.

I'd rewrite your class as follows:

```
class Grade_Calculator(object):
    def __init__(self, score):
        self.score = score

    @property
    def grade(self):
        if self.failure:
            return 'F'
        if 60 <= self.score < 70:
            return 'D'
        if 70 <= self.score < 80:
            return 'C'
        if 80 <= self.score < 90:
            return 'B'
        if 90 <= self.score < 100:
            return 'A'

    @property
    def failure(self):
        return self.score < 60   # returns True or False

    def print_grade(self):
        print self.grade, "- see me" * self.failure

if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = Grade_Calculator(71)
    c.print_grade()
```

Comment: "You have defined failure as a property. Therefore, you can't call it using () notation; in fact, not doing that is kinda the whole point of using a property."... lightbulb moment for me -- thanks. Accepted for thoroughness of answer, although @Paco's was good too.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Grade_Calculator(object):
    def __init__(self, score):
        self.score = score

    @property
    def grade(self):
        grade = self.failure
        if 60 <= self.score < 70:
            grade = 'D'
        elif 70 <= self.score < 80:
            grade = 'C'
        elif 80 <= self.score < 90:
            grade = 'B'
        elif 90 <= self.score < 100:
            grade = 'A'
        return grade

    @property
    def failure(self):
        if self.score < 60:
            print 'See me'
            grade = 'F'
            return grade

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = Grade_Calculator(71)
    print a.grade
```

You're basically creating a new attribute to your object with the failure method. And you're never trying to get its value, that is why you'll never see `'See me'`
By the way, you're overriding the value of grade which was initially an integer. You converted it to a string (`'A'`, `'B'`, `'C'`, ...)
The code I provided works, but I changed a few things. There is no need to call range (this is expensive). You can use `value < variable < other_value` in Python